# CAS JPA Service Registery Table Not Created

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I use [this overlay](https://github.com/Jasig/cas-services-management-overlay) template(version 4.2) for my service management web console.Now I run it and it works in json service registery mode and I want to use JPA service registery and I read documentation on CAS git page for this version [here](https://jasig.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/JPA-Service-Management.html).I follow the instruction there but I get Error below :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "registeredserviceimpl" does not exist
```

Base on documentation the tables should be created automatically if I have privilege Create/Alter .The Table "registeredserviceimpl_props" is created but  table "registeredserviceimpl" is not created after I run the app.I dont know the table schema for this version(4.2.x) to create table manually.
It is my cas-management.properties:

```
cas.host=https://localhost:8443
cas.prefix=${cas.host}
cas.securityContext.casProcessingFilterEntryPoint.loginUrl=${cas.prefix}/login
cas-management.host=https://localhost:2525
cas-management.prefix=${cas-management.host}/cas-management
cas-management.securityContext.serviceProperties.service=${cas-management.prefix}/callback
cas-management.securityContext.serviceProperties.adminRoles=ROLE_ADMIN
pac4j.callback.defaultUrl=/manage.html
cas-management.viewResolver.basename=default_views
svcreg.database.ddl.auto=create-drop
svcreg.database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
svcreg.database.hibernate.batchSize=10
svcreg.database.driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
svcreg.database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CAS-Server
svcreg.database.user=ali
svcreg.database.password=123456
svcreg.database.pool.minSize=6
svcreg.database.pool.maxSize=18
svcreg.database.pool.maxWait=10000
svcreg.database.pool.maxIdleTime=120
svcreg.database.pool.acquireIncrement=6
svcreg.database.pool.idleConnectionTestPeriod=30
svcreg.database.pool.connectionHealthQuery=select 1
svcreg.database.pool.acquireRetryAttempts=5
svcreg.database.pool.acquireRetryDelay=2000
```

and it is my managementConfigContext.xml:

```
<bean>


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<!--
This bean defines the security roles for the Services Management application.  Simple deployments can use the in-memory version.
More robust deployments will want to use another option, such as the Jdbc version.

The name of this should remain "authorizationGenerator" in order for the pac4j security context to find it.
 -->
<util:properties id="userProperties" location="classpath*:user-details.properties" />

<bean id="authorizationGenerator" class="org.pac4j.core.authorization.generator.SpringSecurityPropertiesAuthorizationGenerator">
    <constructor-arg name="properties" ref="userProperties" />
</bean>

<!-- 
Bean that defines the attributes that a service may return.  This example uses the Stub/Mock version.  A real implementation
may go against a database or LDAP server.  The id should remain "attributeRepository" though.
 -->
<bean id="attributeRepository"
      class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao" p:backingMap-ref="backingMap">
</bean>

<util:map id="backingMap">
    <entry key="uid" value="uid"/>
    <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation"/>
    <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership"/>
</util:map>




<bean id="auditTrailManager" class="org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager"/>

<bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        p:driverClass="${svcreg.database.driverClass}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${svcreg.database.url}"
        p:user="${svcreg.database.user}"
        p:password="${svcreg.database.password}"
        p:initialPoolSize="${svcreg.database.pool.minSize}"
        p:minPoolSize="${svcreg.database.pool.minSize}"
        p:maxPoolSize="${svcreg.database.pool.maxSize}"
        p:maxIdleTimeExcessConnections="${svcreg.database.pool.maxIdleTime}"
        p:checkoutTimeout="${svcreg.database.pool.maxWait}"
        p:acquireIncrement="${svcreg.database.pool.acquireIncrement}"
        p:acquireRetryAttempts="${svcreg.database.pool.acquireRetryAttempts}"
        p:acquireRetryDelay="${svcreg.database.pool.acquireRetryDelay}"
        p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="${svcreg.database.pool.idleConnectionTestPeriod}"
        p:preferredTestQuery="${svcreg.database.pool.connectionHealthQuery}"
        />


<util:list id="packagesToScan">
    <value>org.jasig.cas.services</value>
    <value>org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.services</value>
</util:list>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
      id="jpaVendorAdapter"
      p:generateDdl="true"
      p:showSql="true" />

<alias name="jpaServiceRegistryDao" alias="serviceRegistryDao" />
```